How to test that pattern of consoleAppender logback configuration is working using uint tests?
I am very new at logback. I am using logback.xml configuration in my project, that has consoleAppender that use som pattern like
<encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -%kvp- %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

I can see in terminal, that logging pattern is working. But i want to test it in unit tests (like Assertions.assertEqual...). Not only log message, but whole message including time, level, logger, etc (like in pattern, to test it). The point is that i want to test that pattern is working. In future i need to use mask for sensitive data and the goal is to test masking.
Thank you!
I have no idea how to test it.

you have a few options

in your test, programatically get your Logger using static methods of LoggerFactory, add another appender (i.e. ListAppender), run your business code, check what that appender got, remove that appender.

find your real appender (consoleAppender?), switch its output stream to your stub, run your business code, test stubbed output stream content

create entire JoranConfigurator from your (or modified) config not to affect your application

find the encoder api and check that just isolated encoder using the same pattern. and check if you use the same pattern in your production config

create a bash script that will test the output of real, unmodified application


